# How can I get the intersection of a line and a polygon?

Tags: java, intersection

So I have a list of points here.

```
private List<Point> points;
```

and the points class just has x,y,z values but only x,y are used in this case. So I store all the polygon points in there

and then I have this method here.

```
public Point getIntersection(Crossable aLine) {
}
```

And aLine is just two points so it has 4 values total for x1,x2,y1,y2 etc.

I want to get the intersection of the Line and the polygon, I have no understanding of how to get the intersection since there are a lot of variables involved and special cases. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Consider every two adjacent points of the polygon as a line and check to see if it intersects with your line. You need a loop to go through them all.

Comment: And note that you may find the intersection consists of multiple segments.  Also, check the line endpoints first to see if either is inside the polygon, for two special cases (one end inside, both ends inside.)  Even with either or both ends inside you can have multiple segments.  There are many posts here about finding whether a point is inside a polygon so search for that if you need it.